# Library method to partition a collection by a predicate

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have a collection of objects that I would like to partition into two collections, one of which passes a predicate and one of which fails a predicate. I was hoping there would be a [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) method to do this, but the closest they come is [filter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter-java.util.Collection-com.google.common.base.Predicate-), which doesn't give me the other collection.

I would image the signature of the method would be something like this:

```
public static <E> Pair<Collection<E>, Collection<E>> partition(Collection<E> source, Predicate<? super E> predicate)
```

I realize this is super fast to code myself, but I'm looking for an existing library method that does what I want.

Comment: Note that in case of limited set of known in advance partiotion keys it may be much more efficient GC-wise just to iterate the collection once more for each partition key skipping all different-key items on each iteration.

Comment: Another both GC-friendly and encapsulated approach is using Java 8 filtering wrapper streams around original collection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940319/can-you-split-a-stream-into-two-streams

Comment: Anybody know when/where a partition function first appeared in a collections library?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use Guava's [`Multimaps.index`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-).

Here is an example, which partitions a list of words into two parts: those which have length > 3 and those that don't.

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");

ImmutableListMultimap<Boolean, String> partitionedMap = Multimaps.index(words, new Function<String, Boolean>(){
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(String input) {
        return input.length() > 3;
    }
});
System.out.println(partitionedMap);
```

prints:

```
false=[foo, bar], true=[hello, world]
```

Comment: If you already have a Predicate you can turn it into a Function with Functions.forPredicate.

Comment: Update for Java 8: a similar method is also provided in the streaming package `java.util.stream.Collectors#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function<....>)`

It goes like `words.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(func))`

Comment: @PeterandtheWolf i have added an answer based on your suggestion

Answer (score 16):

With the new java 8 features([stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/) and [lambda epressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)), you could write:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");

Map<Boolean, List<String>> partitionedMap =
        words.stream().collect(
                Collectors.partitioningBy(word -> word.length() > 3));

System.out.println(partitionedMap);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (formerly GS Collections), you can use the `partition` method on all `RichIterables`.

```
MutableList<Integer> integers = FastList.newListWith(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3);
PartitionMutableList<Integer> result = integers.partition(IntegerPredicates.isEven());
Assert.assertEquals(FastList.newListWith(-2, 0, 2), result.getSelected());
Assert.assertEquals(FastList.newListWith(-3, -1, 1, 3), result.getRejected());
```

The reason for using a custom type, `PartitionMutableList`, instead of `Pair` is to allow covariant return types for getSelected() and getRejected(). For example, partitioning a `MutableCollection` gives two collections instead of lists.

```
MutableCollection<Integer> integers = ...;
PartitionMutableCollection<Integer> result = integers.partition(IntegerPredicates.isEven());
MutableCollection<Integer> selected = result.getSelected();
```

If your collection isn't a `RichIterable`, you can still use the static utility in Eclipse Collections.

```
PartitionIterable<Integer> partitionIterable = Iterate.partition(integers, IntegerPredicates.isEven());
PartitionMutableList<Integer> partitionList = ListIterate.partition(integers, IntegerPredicates.isEven());
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 2):

seems like a good job for the new Java 12 `Collectors::teeing`:

```
var dividedStrings = Stream.of("foo", "hello", "bar", "world")
            .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                    Collectors.filtering(s -> s.length() <= 3, Collectors.toList()),
                    Collectors.filtering(s -> s.length() > 3, Collectors.toList()),
                    List::of
            ));
System.out.println(dividedStrings.get(0)); //[foo, bar]
System.out.println(dividedStrings.get(1)); //[hello, world]
```

You can find more examples [here](https://adrian.md/2021/05/09/teeing-collector/).

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) [`IterableUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html) provides methods for partitioning `Iterable` objects based on one or more predicates. (Look for the `partition(...)` methods.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in case of limited set of known in advance partiotion keys it may be much more efficient just to iterate the collection once more for each partition key skipping all different-key items on each iteration. As this would not allocate many new objects for Garbage Collector.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear());
LocalDate endExclusive = LocalDate.now().plusYears(1);
List<LocalDate> daysCollection = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
        .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, endExclusive))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<DayOfWeek> keys = Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.values());

for (DayOfWeek key : keys) {
    int count = 0;
    for (LocalDate day : daysCollection) {
        if (key == day.getDayOfWeek()) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("%s: %d days in this year", key, count));
}
```

Another both GC-friendly and encapsulated approach is using Java 8 filtering wrapper streams around the original collection:

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<DayOfWeek, Stream<LocalDate>>> partitions = keys.stream().map(
        key -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                key, daysCollection.stream().filter(
                    day -> key == day.getDayOfWeek())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
// partitions could be passed somewhere before being used
partitions.forEach(pair -> System.out.println(
        String.format("%s: %d days in this year", pair.getKey(), pair.getValue().count())));
```

Both snippets print this:

```
MONDAY: 57 days in this year
TUESDAY: 57 days in this year
WEDNESDAY: 57 days in this year
THURSDAY: 57 days in this year
FRIDAY: 56 days in this year
SATURDAY: 56 days in this year
SUNDAY: 56 days in this year
```