# Can I split a stream into multiple smaller streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There are mulitple questions for streams but for this usecase & in java, didnt find any.

I have a huge stream of objects `Stream<A>` [~1Million objects]. StreamA comes from a file.

```
Class A { enum status [Running,queued,Completed], String name }
```

I want to split `Stream<A>` into three streams without using any Collect statements. **Collect statement loads everything into memory.**

I am facing StackOverflowException as I am calling stream.concat multiple times here.

Stream.Concat has problem mentioned in Java Docs
"Implementation Note:
Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. `Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even StackOverflowException`."

```
Map<Status, Stream<String>> splitStream = new HashMap<>();
streamA.foreach(aObj -> 
Stream<String> statusBasedStream = splitStream.getOrDefault(aObj.status,Stream.of());
splitStream.put(aObj.status, Stream.concat(statusBasedStream, Stream.of(aObj.name)));
```

There are few options where custom streams are available in github to achieve Concatenation but wanted to use standard libraries to solve this.

If data is smaller would have taken a list approach as mentioned here ([Split stream into substreams with N elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127391/split-stream-into-substreams-with-n-elements))

Comment: "Collect statement loads everything into memory." Sure, but putting everything into a map also loads everything into memory. There's no laziness there.

Comment: correct but anything which loads into memory, I would get OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you going to do with the almost 1 million names that are status `Completed`, if not load them into memory?

Comment: I want to write them into file. And FileWriting is factored out into a seperate class. Didnt want to have open file Handlers for diff status(We have almost 6 status). I also want to Gzip the files.

Comment: Just now came across Stream.Builder<String> builderS =  Stream.<String>builder(); I am going to try this. When i did Stream.concat above, since it is lazy loaded, got into StackOverflow. If i load everything into memory getting OOM. I can do file writing, just that my code modularity goes for a toss.

Comment: @VishwaramSankaran What is your issue with having 6 open files? That is nothing, and it is what you need to do for this.

Comment: Agreed it also works. Just that i had factored out file handling into. a separate class. It looks more modular if i have this stream split earlier. I have taken a Function<A, String> rowMapper, need to pass this function also to the file Handler class. I have used this **StreamBuilder**, it had achieved whatever i had intended for. Thanks @Andreas for taking your time.

Comment: A million strings are not that impressive. The fact that you didn’t even realize that all strings are in memory when you collect them into `Stream.Builder` instances, indicates that there is no actual heap memory problem with them. You didn’t say where this `Stream<A>` does come from. Further, it’s not clear what problems you get with `Stream.concat`, when you talk about splitting, the very opposite of what `concat` does.

Comment: Ok taking the solution which andreas proposed with having mulitple file handlers open.

Comment: Why are you calling `concat` multiple times? It seems to be entirely unrelated to the other problem description. Are you processing multiple input files? Stream over the files and use `flatMap`, to create a single stream over the contained elements.

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact solution of the problem but if you have information about the indexes then 
combination of `Stream.skip()` and `Stream.limit()` can help in this - Below is the dummy code that I tried -

```
    int queuedNumbers = 100;
    int runningNumbers=200;
    Stream<Object> all = Stream.of();
    Stream<Object> queuedAndCompleted = all.skip(queuedNumbers);
    Stream<Object> queued = all.limit(queuedNumbers);
    Stream<Object> running = queuedAndCompleted.limit(runningNumbers);
    Stream<Object> completed = queuedAndCompleted.skip(runningNumbers);
```

Hope it would be of some help.