# How to separate a List by a condition using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following code:

```
 List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 List<Integer> even = null;  
 List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
 even = myList.stream()
              .filter(item -> {
                   if(item%2 == 0) { return true;}
                   else { 
                           odd.add(item); 
                           return false;
                   }
              })
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What I am trying to do here is get the even and odd values from a list into separate lists.

The stream `filter()` method returns `true` for even items and the stream collector will collect them.
For the odd case, the filter will return `false` and the item will never reach the collector.

So I am adding such odd numbers in another list I created before under the `else` block.

I know this is not an elegant way of working with streams. For example if I use a parallel stream then there will be thread safety issue with the odd list. I cannot run it multiple times with different filters because of performance reasons (should be O(n)).

This is just an example for one use-case, the list could contain any object and the lambda inside the filter needs to separate them based on some logic into separate lists.

In simple terms: from a list create multiple lists containing items separated based on some criteria.

Without streams it would be just to run a for loop and do simple if-else and collect the items based on the conditions.

Comment: Look into `Collectors.groupingBy` / `Collectors.partitioningBy`

Comment: Potentially answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940319/can-you-split-a-stream-into-two-streams

Comment: `item / 2 == 0` will not separate even and odd numbers. You need `item % 2 == 0` for that

Comment: @BruceFeldman I referred it before. Its not the same. Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could separate elements (numbers) of this list in even and odd numbers:

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> evenAndOdds = myList.stream()
        .collect(partitioningBy(i -> i % 2 == 0));
```

You would get lists of even/odd numbers like this (either list may be empty):

```
List<Integer> even = evenAndOdds.get(true);
List<Integer> odd = evenAndOdds.get(false);
```

You could pass any lambda with required logic in `partitioningBy`.

Comment: When grouping by a condition, you may use `partitioningBy` instead. Besides the possibility to be slightly more efficient, it will always have a result for `true` and `false` in the `Map`, i.e. an empty list if no element fell into that group, rather than `null`.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the insight, updated answer. The empty list vs null is a very useful feature I wasn't aware of and not obvious from the docs.

Comment: that’s a documentation flaw that has already been identified and [fixed in Java 9](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-).