# Continuing stream after `takeWhile`

Tags: java-stream

I have a `Stream` of objects, of which the first part is to be handled differently from the second part (a simple test will tell when to switch).

I've tried to create the stream and use it first with a `takeWhile` and then handle the rest of it:

```
Stream s = [...];

s.takeWhile(simplePredicate).forEach(this::handleFirstPart);
s.forEach(this::handleRest);
```

It doesn't work: it throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`.

Why can't I keep using the stream after `takeWhile` decides to stop its processing?

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940319/can-you-split-a-stream-into-two-streams

Comment: In case if you expect to perform some side-effects using stream elements like in your example without storing them, it's not possible with streams. If you would try to incorporate the state into the stream using dirty hacks, such solution would be broken in parallel.