# java/guava - collect removed elements from iterable

Tags: java, guava

Is there a more elegant way in Guava to remove items which meet a certain predicate from a collection and collect these removed items at the same time? See code below for an example.

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    final List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    list.add("...");
    ...

    final List<String> removedItems = new LinkedList<String>();

    Iterables.removeIf(list, new Predicate<String>() {
        public boolean apply(final String o) {
            if (...) { // some condition
                removedItems.add(o);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    System.out.println(removedItems);
}
```

Thanks!

edit: My question is not about partitioning a list, but about removing elements from a collection and collecting them at the same time. I edited my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10547631/521799

Comment: My question is not about partitioning a list, but about removing elements from a collection and collecting them at the same time. I edited my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I understand. This is why I said *"related"*. Future visitors of this question might be actually looking for a way to partition a list into two lists, which is only subtly different from your approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think it was a good idea to point that out.

Comment: Are my changes sufficient to take this question off hold?

Answer (score 1):

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = new Predicate<>() {
    public boolean apply(final Integer o) {
        return o <= 5;
    }
};

List<Integer> removed = Lists.newLinkedList(Iterables.filter(list, predicate));
Iterables.removeIf(list, predicate);
```

Comment: This iterates twice of the list, which might be/is suboptimal.

Comment: Agreed. It's not more efficient, but it's more elegant (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.add()` returns true if the call to `add()` modifies the collection. So, you can shortcut the `if` / `else` branch like this:

```
Iterables.removeIf(list, new Predicate<Integer>() {
    public boolean apply(final Integer o) {
        return o <= 5 && removedItems.add(o);
    }
});
```

With Java 8, this becomes

```
Iterables.removeIf(list, o -> o <= 5 && removedItems.add(o));
```

... or even (without Guava):

```
list.removeIf(o -> o <= 5 && removedItems.add(o));
```

Of course, not sure if this will be generally perceived as more readable :-)

#### Partitioning a collection by a predicate:

This question here deals with the problem from a different angle:

[Library method to partition a collection by a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10547631/521799)

Comment: This works, but it's generally preferable to avoid side-effects (such as adding to a collection) in a function such as a `Predicate`. Better to have the predicate strictly determine the matching elements and let something else handle adding to a collection.

Comment: @ColinD: I agree. Yet the question is very subjective already, so I figured that *"anything goes"*